# Append two Heterogeneous multi-column files that are aligned by 2 similar columns

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have two files:

File 1:

```
car_type, speed, direction, Lat, Lng  
Ford, 40mph, 120, 32.44, -123.25
```

File 2:

```
Lat, Lng, airplane_type, #_of_passengers, airline  
36.78,-124.21, Boeing 747, 150, United
```

I would like to merge them to create one file that looks like this:

```
car_type, speed, direction, Lat, Lng, airplane_type, #_of_passengers, airline  
Ford,40mph,120,32.44,-123.25,,,
 ,,,36.78,-124.21,Boeing 747,150,United
```

The end result is a combined comma separated file that will always have 3 empty columns at the end of File1 entries and 3 empty columns at the beginning of File2 entries. However, the Lat and Lng fields will be aligned.

I do not want to JOIN on similar values, I want to APPEND the first and second file so that it shares the same columns but not row.

```
Another example  
File 1:
Car_Type, color, speed, lat, lng
Ford, White, 35, 34.567, -123.234
Toyota, Blue,145, 34.657, -123.255
Honda, Black, 25, 35.587, -123.689

File 2:  
Store,lat,lng
Walgreens, 32.123, -123.546
Target, 32.487, -123.594
WalMart, 32.986, -123.165

Result:  
Car_Type, color, speed, lat, lng, Store  
Ford, White, 35, 34.567, -123.234, <NULL>
Toyota, Blue,145, 34.657, -123.255, <NULL>
Honda, Black, 25, 35.587, -123.689, <NULL>
<NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, 32.123, -123.546, Walgreens
<NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, 32.487, -123.594, Target
<NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, 32.986, -123.165, WalMart
```

Looking for a script that will Merge based on column File1 Lat = File2Lat & File1 Lng = File2 Lng so that these columns are assigned to align. The other columns that are not similar just get concatenated. Note: NULL represents just an empty field, no formatting necessary.

Comment: Show more than 1 line per file and explain how you decide on the spacing at the start of the lines from the second file.

Comment: Added some context above

Comment: Really wish you'd shown a couple of lines of input (not including the header) so I didn't have to ask: do you want to interleave the lines form the 2 files or have the whole of file1 followed by the whole of file2? Please update your example to clarify.

Comment: Really appreciate your help...Added another example

Comment: Whole file of 1 followed by the whole file of 2

Comment: Hang on, File2 of your second example doesn't follow the format of your first example. The first example has the Lat and Lng fields at the end of each line in File2 but the second example has it at the start. Which is it? Or could they be anywhere on the line and you need to read the header to figure it out? Are those "**"s in your second example REALLY present (they weren't in your first example)?

Comment: They could be anywhere and the header for both would need to be read to see which columns were the same.  The "**"s are just formatting. Wanted to make the header bold.

Comment: So now you've discovered that you can't make it bold, why not fix it to match reality so the people trying to help you aren't further confused and mis-directed?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
#!/bin/sh
{
echo 'car_type, speed, direction, Lat, Lng, airplane_type, #_of_passengers, airline'
tail -n +2 file1.txt | sed s/$/,,,/
tail -n +2 file2.txt | sed s/^/,,,/
}
```

Explanation:

- Print the new header
- Skip the header of file1, and append `,,,` to the end of the lines
- Skip the header of file2, and prepend `,,,` to the beginning of the lines
- The 3 commands are grouped within `{...}` so you can redirect the whole thing to a file easily

Comment: going to try it... creative approach

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want depending on what you'd want to output if your input files had more than 1 line of data:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR { a[FNR]=$0; next }
  FNR==1  { sub(/([^,]+,){2}/,"") }
  { print a[FNR] (FNR==1 ? "," : ",,,\n,,,") $0 }
' file1 file2
```